# Adding react to the project

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add React to my project. I have already installed react, react-dom, @babel/cli, @babel/core, @babel/preset-react. When i am trying to launch project using

```
<script crossorigin src=" ***react url*** "></script>
<script crossorigin src=" ***react-dom url*** "></script>
```

it works correctly, but when i am trying to remove that lines and add

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

there is nothing displaying on the page. This error appears:

Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

When i am trying to add 'type="module"', the next error appears:

Module loading at "http://localhost:3000/index.js" was blocked due to an unresolved MIME type ("")

All code is listed below

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="keywords" lang="ru" content="Цветы">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Цветы</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="flowers-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<!--
<script crossorigin src=" ***react url*** "></script>
<script crossorigin src=" ***react-dom url*** "></script>
-->

    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.jsx (correctly changing to index.js with command 'npx babel index.jsx --out-file index.js')

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
function HelloWorld(props) {
    return (<h1>Hello, world!! My name is {props.name}</h1>)
}
const RootElement = document.getElementById("root")
const Root = ReactDOM.createRoot(RootElement)
Root.render(HelloWorld({name: "Eugene"}))
```

app.js (used for making server with node.js)

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    let filePath = "index.html";
    if (request.url !== "/") {
        filePath = request.url.substring(1);
    }
    fs.readFile(filePath, function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            response.statusCode = 404;
            response.end("Resource not found!");
        }
        else {
            response.end(data);
        }
    });
}).listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started at 3000");
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "flowershop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "FlowerShop",
  "main": "script.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx babel index.jsx --out-file index.js && node app.js"
  },
  "author": "Hellengi, MorganBlack",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Hellengi/FlowerShop.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "flower"
  ],
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Hellengi/FlowerShop/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Hellengi/FlowerShop#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.1"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
```

I tried to search information in ethernet, but i couldn't fix that problem